# Rename [legal] to [regulations]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retagging

Related to [Are legal questions on topic?](https://drones.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/are-legal-questions-on-topic)

We now have [legal] but I've found from prior experience that people take that tag to mean that all legal questions are on-topic (which nobody has argued for). Instead, we should focus on UAV *regulations* (which should be 100% on-topic). To that end, I'd like to see [legal] be replaced or renamed to [regulations]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we were to change the tag from "legal" to "regulations", I think there should at least be a re-direct, as most people asking (on-topic!) questions about legality will try to tag their question with a "legal" tag, if they haven't been here for long enough to know about a "regulations" tag. Constantly we will have people trying to re-create the "legal" tag if there is not at least a re-direct.

Also, as an alternative to completely removing the tag, we could make the first sentence of the description of the tag, be very clear that not all legal questions are on topic and more information can be found in the FAQ (or wherever the information ends up being). This may also prevent people from asking "off-topic" legal questions. Simply removing the tag will not have this latter effect.

Comment: Sorry, I had meant to say that when we're done, [legal] should be a synonym for [regulations]

Comment: I should also note that very few people pay attention to, let alone heed, warnings in excerpts, which is why I would like to see the tag fixed now rather than when we've had the umpteenth "legal" question that had to be closed

Answer (score 5):

We should rename [legal](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) to [regulations](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regulations) *and* create a synonym. Regulations is the broader term; since many "legal-like" questions aren't actually about legislation, it's the better name for the tag. (Whether the rules are legal isn't a useful distinction, so having both tags is redundant.)

Unless we can get one of those orange warning things ([tag-warnings](/questions/tagged/tag-warnings)) added, we don't have a way of putting a notice on a tag that people will *actually read*; if people asking stuff like "My friend broke my drone; can I sue them?" is something we anticipate, a tag wiki excerpt wouldn't help.

A synonym is necessary because it's natural to add [legal](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) to questions about law; unless it's a synonym or blacklisted, it'll keep being created.